# R - for loop error - subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, for-loop

Hi can anyone help on the codes below? I keep getting error message "Error in splitdata[[i]] : subscript out of bounds". But splitdata is a list with 54 elements.
Any advice appreciated.

```
for (i in (1:54)){
  if(rank == "best"){
    column1[i]<-splitdata[[c(i,1)]]
  }else if(rank == "worst"){
    column1[i]<-splitdata[[c(i,length(splitdata[[i]]))]]
  }else if(rank > length(splitdata[[i]])){
    column1[i]<-"NA"
  }else{
    column1[i]<-splitdata[[c(i,rank)]]}}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: check `length(splitdata)` and `i`.  Other than that, see the previous comment.

Comment: Post `str(splitdata)` ... and is rank supposed to vary with 'i'? At the moment it looks like it would always have the same value.